# Substring function issue

Tags: sql, sas

I have a table as below:

```
PROC_TP
112
5255
5255
5255
112
5255
5255
```

The PROC_TP is numeric with format 6. and I only want to get the first digit so I changed it into character using the put function as:

```
char_PROC_TP=put(PROC_TP,6.);
format char_PROC_TP $6.;
```

Then the table looks like this:

```
PROC_TP        Char_PROC_TP
112            112
5255           5255
5255           5255
5255           5255
112            112
5255           5255
5255           5255
```

Now the char_PROC_TP is character with format of $6.
Then I used the substr function as:

```
first_digit=substr(char_PROC_TP,1,1);
```

Then I don't get any value. So, can anyone tell me what could be the issue with it and its solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because your conversion to character is creating a right justified value.  You can fix it with the justification option on the 6. format as 6.-L.  Also for the first character use the first function it default to length $1.

```
data test;
   input PROC_TP;
   char_proc_tp = put(proc_tp,6.-L);
   first_digit=first(char_PROC_TP);
   cards;
112
5255
5255
5255
112
5255
5255
;;;;
run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

substrN() will take a numeric argument and automatically convert it to character and trim leading and trailing blanks, as necessary.

```
 First = SUBSTRN(num_var, 1, 1);
```

See the [documentation for SUBSTRN](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/69762/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0wqoixcwtx2jqn1ovqf06kart0o.htm).

Comment: Cool.  Link seems to goto the CATX() function page instead of SUBSTRN().  Here is relevant text from man page: If string is numeric, then it is converted to a character value that uses the BEST32. format. Leading and trailing blanks are removed, and no message is sent to the SAS log.

Comment: Link should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [STRIP](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a002295689.htm) function

```
char_PROC_TP=strip(put(PROC_TP,6.));

data test;
 Length FIRST_DIGIT $1;
 input PROC_TP;
 char_proc_tp = strip(put(proc_tp,6.));
 first_digit=substr(char_PROC_TP,1,1);
 datalines;
 112
 5255
 5255
 5255
 112
 5255
 5255
 ;
```